# Show 2 KML files on same GeoGraphic output

Tags: import, geographics

I am trying to recreate John Snow's classic cholera map using KML data files sourced via this [Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2013/mar/15/john-snow-cholera-map#data) ([KML files here](http://blog.rtwilson.com/john-snows-cholera-data-in-more-formats/)).

The KML files are in a zip folder and a simple Import statement generates a GeoGraphics display automatically which is nice.

```
pumpKML = 
  Import["/Users/joe/Documents/z school/SnowGIS_KML/pumps.kml"];
deathsKML = 
  Import["/Users/joe/Documents/z \
school/SnowGIS_KML/cholera_deaths.kml"];
{pumpKML, deathsKML}
```

but how can I show both deaths and pumps on the same output?  I've tried variations of GeoGraphics, Overlay and Show and can't find anything in the help menu.

Comment: How is that you tried `Show` and didn't work? Probably you could share your failed code attempts.

Comment: good grief, I passed it as a list and it's right there in the documentation not to.  The error messages mean nothing to me and I don't have the confidence yet to think that something _should_ work...  Anyone tell me the half-life of mma users when you stop feeling like a complete idiot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

You need to use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).

```
{deaths, pumps} = Import[
  "http://rtwilson.com/downloads/SnowGIS_KML.zip"
  , {"ZIP",
   {
    "SnowGIS_KML\\cholera_deaths.kml",
    "SnowGIS_KML\\pumps.kml"
    }
   }
  ];
Show[deaths, pumps]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### Documentation

`Show[g1, g2,…]` shows several graphics combined.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that for [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) you can directly import several subelements, so we can download the ZIP file and  get the two files of interest in one go.

```
{a,b}=Import[url, {"ZIP",{file1, file2}}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1, you were faster than me :) If you want to make the problem a bit more difficult, you could do something like: `conf = ConformImages[Image /@ {deathsKML, pumpKML}];
{im1, im2} = {RemoveAlphaChannel@conf[[1]], 
   RemoveAlphaChannel@conf[[2]]};
ImageCompose[im1, ColorNegate@im2]`

Comment: @SuTron probably you should out that as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for going the extra step and highlighting multiple element imports - i hadn't figured out what that meant from the documentation till you showed how it worked in this example.